# How can I open multiple files (number of files unknown beforehand) using "with open" statement?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, merge, with-statement

I specifically need to use `with open` statement for opening the files, because I need to open a few hundred files together and merge them using K-way merge. I understand, ideally I should have kept K low, but I did not foresee this problem.

Starting from scratch is not an option now as I have a deadline to meet. So at this point, I need very fast I/O that does not store the whole/huge portion of file in memory (because there are hundreds of files, each of ~10MB). I just need to read one line at a time for K-way merge. Reducing memory usage is my primary focus right now.

I learned that `with open` is the most efficient technique, but I cannot understand how to `open` all the files together in a single `with open` statement. Excuse my beginner ignorance!

**Update:** This problem was solved. It turns out the issue was not about how I was opening the files at all. I found out that the excessive memory usage was due to inefficient garbage collection. I did not use `with open` at all. I used the regular `f=open()` and `f.close()`. Garbage collection saved the day.

Comment: I don't think `with open` is any more efficient than `f = open() ... close(f)`. It is supposed to be more convenient, but it sounds like that is not the case in your situation. You can just open a bunch of files and keep the file objects in a list.

Comment: `with` statement has nothing to do with efficiency, it only makes sure that the file will be closed implicitly(even if an exception occurs). As @MarkkuK said, you can store the references to the file objects in a list and then close them manually at the end, and use a try-finally block to make sure that the files are closed even if an error occurs.

Comment: Thank you both for the fast responses. Can you suggest an alternative where the memory usage will not be so high even if I open a few hundred files together? Since I just need one line at a time from these files, I think it would help if I use some technique that does not load large portion of the files in buffer.

Comment: So, you want to read all lines from first file first and then from second line... etc or you want to read first line from each file and then second line from each file....?

Comment: Use the `readline`-method of file objects to read a single line. repeated use will retrive the next line each time: `f = open(file); f.readline(); f.readline(); ...; f.close()`

Comment: Have a look at the equivalents of the with statement: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary No. I want to merge K already sorted index files. So at first I read the 1st word (1st word from the 1st line actually) from all the K files, put them in priority queue, and pop the smallest(in lexical order) word. I go to that specific file from where the smallest element had originated and increment the file pointer for that file(ie. go to the second line of that file) and put it in the priority queue, pop the smallest word and so on. I manually close each of the files, once they reach end of file.

Comment: @SatarupaGuha I guess then storing file objects in a list looks like the best way to do this. First call `next` on each file to get one line from all file objects, and then in then next step call `next` on the file object that was selected as the minimum one to get the next line from that file, this way will you're going to store only one from each file at a time in memory. Don't use `file.read` or `file.readlines` as they load everything into memory, file objects are iterable in Python. And finally close all the file objects to free up resources explicitly.

Comment: I was using file.readline() that reads one line in memory. But I did not collect garbage properly. There was a significant memory leak, because of which the memory use was so high. After I changed that, my program worked fine even with 600 files open at the same time. I did not have to use "with open".

Answer (score 5):

It's fairly easy to write your own context manager to handle this by using the built-in [`contextmanger`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) function decorator to define "a factory function for `with` statement context managers" as the documentation puts it. For example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def multi_file_manager(files, mode='rt'):
    """ Open multiple files and make sure they all get closed. """
    files = [open(file, mode) for file in files]
    yield files
    for file in files:
        file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    filenames = 'file1', 'file2', 'file3'

    with multi_file_manager(filenames) as files:
        a = files[0].readline()
        b = files[2].readline()
            ...
```

---

If you don't know all the files ahead of time, it would be equally easy to create a context manager that supported adding them incrementally with the context. In the code below, a [`contextlib.ContextDecorator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator) is used as the base class to simplify the implementation of a `MultiFileManager` class.

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator

class MultiFileManager(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self, files=None):
        self.files = [] if files is None else files

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        for file in self.files:
            file.close()

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        """Add file to be closed when leaving context."""
        self.files.append(other)
        return self


if __name__ == '__main__':

    filenames = 'mfm_file1.txt', 'mfm_file2.txt', 'mfm_file3.txt'

    with MultiFileManager() as mfmgr:
        for count, filename in enumerate(filenames, start=1):
            file = open(filename, 'w')
            mfmgr += file  # Add file to be closed later.
            file.write(f'this is file {count}\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

While not a solution for 2.7, I should note there is one good, correct solution for 3.3+, [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack), which can be used to do this *correctly* (surprisingly difficult to get right when you roll your own) and nicely:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with open('source_dataset.txt') as src_file, ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname, 'w')) for fname in fname_list]
    ... do stuff with src_file and the values in files ...
... src_file and all elements in stack cleaned up on block exit ...
```

Importantly, if any of the `open`s fails, all of the `open`s that succeeded prior to that point will be cleaned up deterministically; most naive solutions end up failing to clean up in that case, relying on the garbage collector at best, and in cases like lock acquisition where there is no object to collect, failing to ever release the lock.

Posted here since this question was marked as the "original" for a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39782888/364696) that didn't specify Python version.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(...) as f: 
    # do stuff
```

translates roughly to

```
f = open(...)
# do stuff
f.close()
```

In your case, I wouldn't use the `with open` syntax. If you have a list of filenames, then do something like this

```
filenames = os.listdir(file_directory)
open_files = map(open, filenames)
# do stuff
for f in open_files:
    f.close()
```

If you really want to use the `with open` syntax, you can make your own context manager that accepts a list of filenames

```
class MultipleFileManager(object):
    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files = files

    def __enter__(self):
        self.open_files = map(open, self.files)
        return self.open_files

    def __exit__(self):
        for f in self.open_files:
            f.close()
```

And then use it like this:

```
filenames = os.listdir(file_directory)
with MulitpleFileManager(filenames) as files:
    for f in files:
        # do stuff
```

The only advantage I see to using a context manager in this case is that you can't forget to close the files. But there is nothing wrong with manually closing the files. And remember, the os will reclaim its resources when your program exits anyway.

Comment: Why are you creating a list of `None`s just to close the files?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary What do you mean by list of Nones?

Comment: `map(lambda x: x.close(), self.open_files)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary ahh nice catch. changing it to a for loop. Although looking at the discussion I don't think my answer is what they want