# How to "with open" a list of files and obtain their handles in python?

Tags: python, with-statement

Is it possible to `with open()` all files contained in a list and create file handles for writing?

For example, if my function accepts a list of filenames for data-splitting in a machine learning task,

`fname_list = ['train_dataset.txt', 'validate_dataset.txt', 'test_dataset.txt']`

then it would be convenient to be able to do:

```
with open('source_dataset.txt) as src_file, open(name_list, 'w') as <DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_DO_HERE>:
```

And perform some data splitting within the block.

**Edit: So my question is basically "Is it possible to obtain multiple file handles for a list of files opened with 'with open()'?"**

Comment: I am not sure about how to create multiple file handles for the list of files.
...open(name_list, 'w') as <DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_DO_HERE>:

Comment: Why not iterate over a list of filenames, open and read them, and store the string data for each one in a list to be used later?

Comment: Since a dataset may contain millions of lines, wouldn't doing such increase the overhead to (1 million) x len(list_of_filenames) ?

Or perhaps this is some optimization I should not worry about?

Comment: Well still. Just iterate over the file name list, and open each file. Then do your business with that file. Whether it's reading the text or whatever.

Comment: I see what you meant. Open each file and save respective file handle into a list, perform read and write, and then close all handles in the list?

But I suppose "with open()" cannot be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.3 and higher, [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) can be used to do this correctly and nicely:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with open('source_dataset.txt') as src_file, ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname, 'w')) for fname in fname_list]
    ... do stuff with src_file and the values in files ...
... src_file and all elements in stack cleaned up on block exit ...
```

Comment: `ExitStack` is an especially good tool for this because it behaves nicely even if an exception occurs when opening one of the later files (after previous ones were opened successfully). Most naive solutions will leak open files in that situation (until the garbage collector cleans up the file objects).

Comment: @Blckknght: Yup. I didn't want to go into the details for fear of masking the simplicity (the docs link covers it anyway), but yeah, the fact that it does it _correctly_ is not a small thing, as you say.