# open multiple files saved as dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics, biopython

User's input are the names of the experiments and a file with data. After data manipulation I have saved in a dict which sample (row) in the file corresponds to which experiment.
For example, (sometimes sample can belong to either several experiments, or one or none)

```
exp_sample["sample1"]=['experiment5','experiment6']
exp_sample["sample3"]=['experiment5']
```

While parsing the datafile again (for the second time) I want to write the sample row into the corresponding experiment file. Meaning, all experiment files should be opened while I am parsing through the datafile. My idea is following:

```
experiment_files = {exp: open(exp+".fastq",'w') for exp in experiments}
for read in SeqIO.parse(fastq, 'fastq'):
    experiment = exp_sample[sample.id]
    #if sample belongs only to one experiment
    #or sample belongs to two the same experiments
    if len(experiment)==1 or (len(exp)==2 and (exp[0]==exp[1]))
        SeqIO.write(read,exp_files[experiment[0]],'fastq')
(x.close() for x in experiment_files.values())
```

My question is, is it legit to open the files saved in the `dict` and then close them in that way? Or is there any other cleverer way of doing it?

PS. I know, I could have saved the sample rows into the lists of corresponding experiments and then write all experiment record in an experiment file but the datafile can be of several GB.

Comment: I think you should use context manager in a loop over `experiments`, instead of iterating twice on `experiments` using the `with` statement

Comment: @OrDuan I do not iterate twice on experiments, I iterate twice over datafile, namely SeqIO.parse(fastq, 'fastq')

Comment: It should be legal to do so, although using a generator expression like that at the end, just for its side-effects, is considered a poor practice. You can formalize it by using what is shown in this [answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21683192/355230) to another question.

Comment: That generator expression won't do anything. The equivalent list comprehension `[x.close() for x in experiment_files.values()]` _will_ work, but it's bad practice to make a list that you immediately throw away. Just use a plain `for`  loop: `for x in experiment_files.values():  x.close()`

Answer (score 0):

After we discussed at the comment I update my original answer.

If you want to open multiple files, you can do it with the context manager [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack).

Here is an example code:

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
```

Each element in the `files` list represent one file that you open.

Comment: It would have been better if you'd just modified your original answer. Remember, deleted answers aren't actually deleted: anyone with 10k+ rep can see them.

Comment: @OrDuan I am saving the the opened files in the dictionary because I need access to them according to the experiment name `SeqIO.write(read,exp_files[experiment[0]],'fastq')`

Comment: @Anni you still can use the dict you created. something like this: `{exp: stack.enter_context(open(exp+".fastq",'w')) for exp in experiments}` so you won't have to use the `close` method